# Невозможно преобразовать Array в Object[][]

Tags: google-apps-script

Пытаюсь записать в диапазон листа массив, но получаю ошибку:

> Невозможно преобразовать Array в Object[][](строка 63)

Ниже - часть кода, в котором формируется массив:

```
var j=0;
  while (j < Recipt.length && Recipt[j][1] != "" && Recipt[j][1] !=0 ){
    Stock.push({row: i + j});
    Stock[i+j][0]=sheetE.getRange("F2").getValues(); // Заносим в Stock дату Накладной
    Stock[i+j][1]=sheetE.getRange("D2").getValues(); // Заносим в ID Накладной
    Stock[i+j][2]=sheetE.getRange("D4").getValues(); // Заносим в Stock вид Накладной
    Stock[i+j][3]=Recipt[j][0]; // Заносим в Журнал ID товара
    Stock[i+j][4]=Recipt[j][1]; // Заносим в Журнал Артикул товара
    Stock[i+j][5]=Recipt[j][4]; // Заносим в Журнал количество товара
    Stock[i+j][8]=new Date();// Заносим дата и время транзакции
    j++;
  }
  sheetJ.insertRows(Stock.length+3-j, j);//Вставляем строки после последней полной строки
  sheetJ.getRange(4,2).setValues(Stock);
```

ошибка возникает в последней строке. Такое ощущение, что ее причина в том, что массив по какой-то причине получается не двумерный, а массив массивов (в дебагере видны лишние скобки и лишние уровни).

Answer (score 1):

- `getValues()` возвращает двумерный массив
- `getValue()` возвращает значение *первой* ячейки диапазона

Пожалуйста, не делайте `getRange()` внутри циклов - это плохо. См. 
[Best Practices/Use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)

```
   function myfunction() {

  /*
    Stock[i+j][0]=sheetE.getRange("F2").getValues(); // Заносим в Stock дату Накладной
    Stock[i+j][1]=sheetE.getRange("D2").getValues(); // Заносим в ID Накладной
    Stock[i+j][2]=sheetE.getRange("D4").getValues(); // Заносим в Stock вид Накладной
  */
  var commondata = sheetE.getRange("D2:F4").getValues();

  var date = new Date(); // время транзакции

  var j = 0;
  while (j < Recipt.length && Recipt[j][1] != "" && Recipt[j][1] != 0) {
    Stock.push({
      row: i + j
    });
    Stock[i + j][0] = commondata[0][2]; // Заносим в Stock дату Накладной
    Stock[i + j][1] = commondata[0][0]; // Заносим в ID Накладной
    Stock[i + j][2] = commondata[2][0]; // Заносим в Stock вид Накладной
    Stock[i + j][3] = Recipt[j][0]; // Заносим в Журнал ID товара
    Stock[i + j][4] = Recipt[j][1]; // Заносим в Журнал Артикул товара
    Stock[i + j][5] = Recipt[j][4]; // Заносим в Журнал количество товара
    Stock[i + j][8] = date; // Заносим дата и время транзакции
    j++;
  }

  // sheetJ.insertRows(Stock.length + 3 - j, j); //Вставляем строки после последней полной строки
  // sheetJ.getRange(4, 2).setValues(Stock);
  appendValues(sheetJ, Stock, 2);

}

function appendValues(sheet, values, columnStart) {
  columnStart = columnStart || 1;
  return sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, columnStart, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Насчет getValues, разобрался. была и еще она проблема: Stock.push({
    row: i + j
  }); также делал запись многомерную в массив, заменил ее на Stock.push([[10]]); стало лучше работать, но осталась маленькая ошибка: диапазон вставлялся но  ругался на его размерность. После того как всем элементам массива Stock присвоил значения "", ошибок не стало, но пришлось много лишнего кода добавить связанного с присвоением  значений. Можно ли одной строчкой присвоить одно и тоже значение всем элементам массива? Насчет Best Practice for batch operations - конечно учту, просто пока отладка идет

Comment: @Sturmer, у вас отладка, а на форуме должны гадать что и как? Синтаксис вашей функции неверен. Так не делают. Попробуйте метод `appendValues`. Консультации https://google-apps-script-russian.gitlab.io/page/about/